# How to customize currency formatting in MessageFormat in ICU4J

Tags: java, internationalization, icu, messageformat

I have a system that generates a lot of documents. Its contents are defined in ResourceBundles.

I want to customize the way MessageFormat prints currency values. Sometimes I want it to display currencies without fraction digits (but not always).

This should be working as expected but it is not:

```
System.err.println(
  com.ibm.icu.text.MessageFormat.format(
      "{0,number,\u00A4#}", 
      new com.ibm.icu.util.CurrencyAmount(1, 
        com.ibm.icu.util.Currency.getInstance("USD"))));
```

Unfortunately it prints out:

```
US$1,00
```

Does anyone of you use custom formats for currency in resource bundle 'properties' files?

I don't want to change it system wide.

And by the way this works fine with java.text.MessageFormat.

Comment: Any reasons why you can't use JDK version then? And by the way: is there any specific reason why you can't use `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale)`?

Comment: There are two reasons why I want to use ICU. First is that our  application needs to print certain currencies in different locales which is not possible in JDK version (currency must be independent on current locale), second is that ICU has spellout formatting which is also must be print in different locales. And I don't want to use 'NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale)' since all my messages are in ResourceBundles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I read your question once again.
I don't really know why you want to chop down the cents part (in US, it makes sense in Korea or Japan as they don't use them at all).
Anyway, I don't think it is a good idea to just cut-off cents part, but if you want to do it, it is as simple as using NumberFormat with [setMaximumIntegerDigits(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#setMaximumIntegerDigits%28int%29).

BTW, I still don't know I know why by using resource bundles you can't use [NumberFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html).
You still can call formatter in `MessageFormat.format()`:

```
NumberFormat currencyFormatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);
currencyFormatter.setMaximumFractionDigits(0);
System.err.println(MessageFormat.format("Some amount: {0}.",
        currencyFormatter.format(1d)));
```

Predictably it prints out:

> Some amount: $1.

If you need to retain the currency, I'd suggest to play with `setCurrency(Currency)` method by retain local format - you are asking this question in Internalization tag anyway.

---

**Edit: Including information about MessageFormat capabilities**

If you need to use custom currency formats for a Locale, you actually need to instantiate MessageFormat class (regular static `MessageFormat.format(String, Object...)` won't work in web applications for it uses default Locale - `Locale.getDefault(Locale.Category.FORMAT)` in Java 7 - server Locale if you prefer).

So what you really want is to write a helper method (sorry, no bonus) that will look similar to this (out of memory, sorry):

```
public static String format(String pattern, Locale locale, Object... args) {
  final String emptyPattern = "";
  final FieldPosition zero = new FieldPosition(0);
  MessageFormat fmt = new MessageFormat(emptyPattern, locale);
  StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer(); // I just love it...

  fmt.applyPattern(pattern);
  fmt.format(args, buf, zero);

  return buf.toString();
}
```

For performance reasons, you might think of creating StringBuffer once and then clean it all the time, but I leave optimizations to yourself.
You also would need to modify patterns a bit and I will explain in a moment why:

```
String pattern = "{1}{0,number,\u00A4#}";
```

You would need to pass the amount and the currency symbol and left to translators where to place the symbol and how to format value for a Locale (don't forget to add comments to properties file!).

Comment: Thanks for your quick help. I didn't describe my problem enough. In our system we generate a lot of documents which need to be in a compliance with formal guidelines. Some of amounts need to have nothing as the cents part (e.g. for Poland a formal way is to add 2 figures in the cents part but we need to cut them down) but in other situations we stick to a standard way of presenting money. So it is not an option to set fraction digits on a system wide formatter. And creating different formatters in java for single messages taken from ResourceBundles will be pain in the ass.

Comment: Let me explain why your solution does not work first: [http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/util/CurrencyAmount.html] CurrencyAmount does not derive from Number, therefore plain toString() will be called during formatting. It won't work for you. Now, take a look at my edit :)